# Doxygen python linking to functions

Tags: python, documentation, module, namespaces, doxygen

I'm using Doxygen to document my python module and I'm trying to get it to link to a function in-text. I can get it to link to the function's namespace ok but not to the function itself.

E.g. `ModuleName::Namespace` works but `ModuleName::Namespace::getSomething()` doesn't.

How do I get these links to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doxygen automatically wraps functions in a namespace per module. You have to document this module in order to make the documentation visible and linkable (or use EXTRACT_ALL = YES).

Here is an example `func.py`

```
## @package func
#  Module docs

## A function
#
#  More documentation.
def foo():
    print "Hello World!"

## Another function.
#
#  This function simply calls foo()
def bar():
    foo()
```

And another function `another.py`:

```
## @package another
#
#  Another module

import func

## This function calls func.foo()
def another():
     foo()
```

You should see that foo() and func.foo() will be automatically linked.

Comment: I've had success using @namespace as well